# IorD Control Signal in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

Why is the control signal called IorD? What does the name stand for?
Couldn't find any documentation about this.

[image]

Comment: `Instruction or Data`. Now that you know, you can use google to find out more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular MIPS datapath diagram shows a shared memory used for both instructions and data.

In the above design, since the memory is shared for both instructions and data, there needs to be a control that tells that mux which address to use for a memory access, whether `PC` (Instruction fetch) or `ALUOut` (Data access) — hence `IorD`.

An alternative (a more popular design) has separate Instruction Memory and Data Memory.  When the Instruction Memory and Data Memory are separated, there is no need for a `IorD` mux control signal because the Instruction Memory always sources `PC` for the address and the Data Memory always sources `ALUOut` for the address.  (`MemRead` and `MemWrite` are still necessary for the Data Memory.)  You can see this by searching for "MIPS single cycle datapath" for images.